# How to make a curved layout like the one in the photo

Tags: android, android-layout, layer-list, android-shape

I am trying to make the layout below (picture 1) like the one in the photo (picture 2) but I don't know how to implement it. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!-- Background -->
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#2b2c2e" />
        <size android:height="100dp"
            android:width="100dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- Curved shape -->
  <item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="0.5dp"
            android:color="#1d1d20" />
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="150dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <gradient
            android:angle="45"
            android:endColor="#1f5993"
            android:centerColor="#316bb7"
            android:startColor="#1f5993" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image: xml]
[image: Curved Button]

Comment: You can always try overlapping images/views...

Comment: I tried to use other shapes on top of the existing but the result was not good at all...

Comment: Create your Desired Shape in Photoshop, then create a pressed version of it.. then U can create a Custom button with them...

Comment: Thank you so much @SyedAliNaqi ! I will follow your advice.

Comment: I am Happy to Help!!